# draw by mouse in openGL

Tags: opengl, mouse, draw

How do you draw a polygon by mouse with openGL in C++?

Answer (score 12):

Start by conditioning the mouse to recognize the shape of a polygon and be able to complete one it sees on a computer screen. You can use operant conditioning (by rewarding the mouse with a food pellet) to train it to an acceptable level of proficiency.

Comment: lol I was gonna downvote before a I realized this was a homework question, +1

Answer (score 5):

Assuming this is homework, and that you want to try to figure this out for yourself before looking at someone else's solution, take a moment to think about:

- How do you know when the user push a button?
- What are the mouse coordinates at that time?
- How do you translate the mouse coordinates to the world coordinates of your GL-model?
- How do you figure out which vertex to move?  (or add)
- How do you move the vertex?
- How do you redraw?
- What is the connection between model and view?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe go to class, pay attention, and learn what the teacher says?  Or look at the NeHe tutorials, which you can find through five minutes of using the almighty Google?